# Swift memory will not release

Tags: ios, swift, memory, automatic-ref-counting, swift3

I have a class that get all the user assets, get the image and then perform face detection on each of the images. I am calling my class from the viewDidLoad function like this:

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {

    _ = autoreleasepool{

        return faceProcessing()    
    }
  }
```

And this is the class:

```
class faceProcessing{

let manager = PHImageManager.default()
let option = PHImageRequestOptions()

init() {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    let assets = getAssets(realm: realm)

    option.isSynchronous = true
    option.deliveryMode = .fastFormat
    option.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true

    var featuresCount = 0

    for assetIndex in 0...assets.count-1{


        featuresCount += autoreleasepool{() -> Int? in
            print(assetIndex)
            var facesCount = 0
           faceDetection(asset: assets[assetIndex]) { (features) in
                facesCount = features
            }

            return facesCount
        }!
    }

    print(featuresCount)    
}

func getAssets(realm: Realm)->[PHAsset]{

    return autoreleasepool{ () -> [PHAsset] in
    let images = realm.objects(Image.self).filter("asset != nil")
    let ids: [String] = images.map {$0.id}
    let options = PHFetchOptions()
    options.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: true)]
    let assets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withLocalIdentifiers: ids, options: options)
    var assetArray = [PHAsset]()

    if(assets.count > 1){
            for assetIndex in 0...assets.count-1{
            assetArray.append(assets[assetIndex])
        }
    }
    return assetArray
    }
}

func faceDetection(asset: PHAsset, completionHandler:@escaping (Int)->Void){    
  manager.requestImageData(for: asset, options: option){
        (data, responseString, imageOriet, info) in
        if (data != nil){
           weak var faceDetector = CIDetector(ofType: CIDetectorTypeFace, context: nil, options: [CIDetectorAccuracy: CIDetectorAccuracyHigh])

            let faces = (faceDetector?.features(in: CIImage(data: data!)!))
            faceDetector = nil
            completionHandler((faces?.count)!)
        }else{
            print(info)
        }

    }
}
}
```

The problem is that after finishing the process of getting the images and detecting the faces, the memory will not release. Before the process the memory was about 60MB, during the process it was between 400MB to 500MB, and when the process finished it went back to 300MB. Is there is a way I could release the entire memory and have 60MB after the process will finish ?

Here is how the instruments looks:

[image]
[image]

It looks like the face detection is not releasing its memory, so its there is a way I could release the CIDetection from memory?

Comment: Have you used the instruments leaks tool to confirm that this memory is still allocated and you aren't just seeing the high water mark of memory usage

Comment: In the instruments leaks tool I could see in the top at allocations that the memory after the processing is 300MB. Do you know any way I could deallocate the memory?

Comment: What does is the value of "persistent bytes" in the allocation summary for all heaps & anonymous vm ?

Comment: I get 329.70MB.

Comment: You should select the "call tree" under "details" and you can drill down to see where the memory is being allocated

Comment: I add images from my instrument. I don't know how to release the memory from the CIDetector.